# how to pass the key as select option value from v-for when changed (VueJS)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, select, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm working with `Vue 3` and `Bootstrap 5`.

I have a `select` with multiple options. Now I'm displaying my `option.TEXT` and this `value` will also be passed into my methods when I change something. But I want to pass the `key` **(option.ID)** when I change something.

But I also want my `v-model` to be my `option.ID` but displaying my `option.TEXT`.

How can I achieve this without checking it in the methods itself.

***SELECT:***

```
<select class="form-select" v-model="value" @change="get_key()">
    <option v-for="option in options" :key="option.ID">
        {{ option.TEXT }}
    </option>
</select>
```

***OPTIONS ARRAY:***

```
[
  {  "ID": 1,
     "TEXT": "One"
  },
  {  "ID": 2,
     "TEXT": "Two"
  },
  {  "ID": 3,
     "TEXT": "Three"
  },
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `option` attribute value should be bound to the `option.ID` :

```html
<select class="form-select" v-model="value" @change="get_key()">
    <option v-for="option in options" :key="option.ID" :value="option.ID">
        {{ option.TEXT }}
    </option>
</select>
```